# foreach not initialising the loop variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using a foreach to loop through an IList of objects in a Partial View in ASP.NET MVC.

Here's the entire code (Message is one of my classes from the Model).

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IList<Message>>" %>

<%
if (ViewData.Model.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (MvcTest.Models.Message m in ViewData.Model)
    {
        Response.Write(m.RenderHtml()); 
    }
}

%>
```

For some reason, this generates a CS0165 on the ResponseWrite - complaining that m may not be initialised.

I rewrote it like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IList<Message>>" %>

<%
//Can't see why I have to declare this as a variable, but I get CS0165 if I use ViewData.Model directly in the foreach
IList<MvcTest.Models.Message> messages = ViewData.Model;
if (messages.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (MvcTest.Models.Message m in messages)
    {
        Response.Write(m.RenderHtml()); 
    }
}

%>
```

ie explicitly declaring a variable for the IList rather than just using the (strongly-typed) Model, and it works fine.

Can anyone explain why what I did fixes the problem?

Comment: What is the exact type of "ViewData.Model" property?

Comment: Can you show the code you used to generate the list of messages? My guess is that's where your error lies. If this is Linq2SQL or Entities Framework you probably just lack a "Load" statement.

Comment: What happens if you cast `ViewData.Model` to `IEnumerable<MvcTest.Models.Message>`?

Comment: @Alxandr: Wrong.  This is a compile-time error.

Comment: Ever heard of the var keyword?

Comment: That if statement around the foreach is pointless btw.

Comment: @Richard Are you sure the two references to `Message` are the same? `IList<Message>` could be any old `Message`. If you use `var` in the `foreach`, you only need to specify it correctly once.

Comment: I would also remove the if statement, its not needed here.

Comment: @SwDevMan81 Don't hate on the code style. Find the reason for the CS0165 instead! :)

Comment: @bzlm - Maybe its the if statement :P

Comment: Can you post the code for RenterHtml? Likely the problem is in there.

Comment: @SwDevMan: Wrong on both counts.

Comment: @Bzlm you're right - I've accepted SLaks' answer as that was the same.

Comment: @Bzlm: Not quite.  This error happens if the type being enumerated cannot be resolved.  Had there been two `Message` classes, he would have gotten a conversion error.

Comment: @SLaks, thanks for the clarification - I guess that the fact that Models and Views are in different namespaces is the underlying explanation.

Comment: @Richard No, that's not it in this case. But within Web Form views, you can import namespaces (either in Web.config or in the view) to enable resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the `Inherits` declaration to

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.Collections.Generic.IList<MvcTest.Models.Message>>"
```

I'm not sure whether it will help, though.

Comment: You mean `System.Collections.Generic.IList`?

Comment: Probably don't need to do this for IList, but for the particular message I think it would be wise.

Comment: I've just done IList<MvcTest.Models.Message> and that has resolved it.

Thank you very much.